# Sequences and Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

A question I saw asked to prove that if $x_n \to L$ where $x_n \neq 0$ $\forall {n}\in\Bbb N$ and $L\neq0$ then there exists a constant $C\gt0$ such that $|x_n|\ge C$ $\forall n$

I suppose first I use the definition for convergence using epsilon and N but after that point I'm just stuck and I'd appreciate at least some direction to where I could find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Naively, for every sufficiently large $n$, $x_n$ will be as close as you want to $L$. Since $L \neq 0$, that means you have plenty of space to avoid $0$. Can you make this rigorous ?

Comment: It's the good way, but it requires to see clearly what means all these inequalities. If you go far enough (there exists $N$ such that...) then $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$, id est $x_n$ is "$\epsilon$-close to" L. What does it imply about $x_n$ ? Can $x_n$ be still null if $\epsilon$ becomes very small ? Actually no, because $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$ means $x_n - L < \epsilon \implies x_n < L + \epsilon$ but also $L - x_n < \epsilon \implies x_n > L - \epsilon$ ! In others words, $L-\epsilon < x_n < L+\epsilon$. I let you pick a well-choosen $\epsilon$ to finish the proof

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP specifies $x_n \ne 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Indeed it does, @goos. There goes a comment...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also proceed by contradiction: assume that the conclusion is false. Then, for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $C=C_k=\frac{1}{k}$ you could find indices $n_1<n_2<n_3<\ldots <n_k<n_{k+1}<\ldots$ such that $|x_{n_k}|\leq \frac{1}{k}$. But $\lim_k x_{n_k}=L$ and $\lim_k \frac{1}{k}=0$, so that $|L| \leq 0$. This means $L=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: IMO proceeding by contradiction is a bit overkill for this trivial property where direct proof is straightforward...

Comment: Yes, but it is another viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

- Show that there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $\tfrac12 L \le x_n \le \tfrac32 L$.
- Pick $C = \min\left\{|x_1|, |x_2|, |x_3|, \ldots, |x_N|, \tfrac12 |L|\right\}$.